# Placeholder attribute not supported in IE. Any suggestions?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html

What do you all use to support placeholder attributes in browsers?

Currently, am using:

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin

Have also tried this plugin to no avail:

https://github.com/danbentley/placeholder

But it doesn't seem to work with IE... More specifically IE 8. Any other suggestions / alternatives?

Should I forget about the placeholder attribute for now?

Comment: If IE8 support is fundamental then, yes, you should forget about features it doesn't support.  If placeholders would be nice for your users but are not fundamental then use them and don't worry about IE8.

Comment: If they are fundamental, then you are using them wrong. A hint should never be an essential requirement to understand an input.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Not quite, still looking

Comment: this is the best plugin i've seen to date for placeholder. *knock on wood* [click here to see demo & download](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/)

Comment: @user1521182: It doesn't have a value hook so `.val()` does not return empty in case the element currently has the placeholder "value" but no a real one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right that IE8 doesn't support the `placeholder` attribute. `placeholder` is part of the HTML5 spec, and IE8 was released a long time before HTML5 was thought of.

The best way to deal with it in a seamless manner is to use a tool like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect whether the browser has support for the placeholder feature, and run a JS polyfill script if it isn't supported.

```
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
    //insert placeholder polyfill script here.
}
```

There are numerous placeholder polyfill scripts out there to download. Pick one which makes use of the `placeholder` attribute so that you only need to define the placeholder string in one place for all browsers. Here's one you could try: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem here is, even the JS polyfill scripts don't seem to work with IE

Comment: Another good resource, has a list of links in the 'placeholder' section: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: I think there is a typo or two in line 1: `if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {`

Comment: @rwalter - yes there is. I'll fix it. :) (btw, you can also fix typos like this yourself if you spot them; Stackoverflow encourages constructive edits)

Comment: You still need to add  `!` there! Actually I did try to edit it but for some reason SO wouldn't let me - something to do with not making enough of a change.

Comment: @rwalter - ah, yes. D'oh. Hmm, yeah, you're right; small changes can be rejected for being too minor. Sometimes that's a good thing; sometimes it's a pain.

Answer (score 6):

Here's code straight from my project that works natively in chrome and uses the polyfill in IE8... there's an alert in here for testing that shows when the polyfill is being called. 
You need modernizr loaded as a prerequisite to using this code but a simple script include in your `<head>` section will do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {
        if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
            $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                    input.removeClass('placeholder');
                }
            }).blur(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.addClass('placeholder');
                    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                   }
            }).blur();

            $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
                $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                        input.val('');
                    }
                })
            });

            alert("no place holders");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This will bring problems if we'll use placeholdered values in javascript. We'll get text instead of the actual empty strings which meant to be.

Comment: what i did in my project to prevent this was on the submit event if the text value was equal to the placeholder value i set the value to null. It's still a bit hacky, but unfortunately supporting older browsers tends to get that way sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few polyfill scripts for the placeholder attribute. Here's [one that seems to work well](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin).

Just remember to call `$('input, textarea').placeholder();` in your JS code, and possibly add a CSS rule, eg. `.placeholder { color: #aaa }`.

Answer (score 2):

With all the other answers and examples I've been looking at, I found some problems. I wrote my own solution to resolve these issues and decided to post it here. The 2 things my code will handle correctly that the other solutions seem to have problems with are:

1. If you actually happen to want to input the text contained in the placeholder as the value, my code won't assume that this is the placeholder and discard your input.
2. If you press the refresh button in IE, it doesn't autopopulate the fields with the placeholder values.

Include Modernizr and JQuery as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

Add some CSS such as:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.placeholder {
    color: #aaa;
}
</style>
```

Then the main code you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Only do anything if the browser does not support placeholders
    if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {

        // Format all elements with the placeholder attribute and insert it as a value
        $('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
                $(this).addClass('placeholder');
            }
            $(this).focus(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder') && $(this).hasClass('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
                }
            }).blur(function() {
                if($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
                    $(this).addClass('placeholder');
                }
            });
        });

        // Clean up any placeholders if the form gets submitted
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder') && $(this).hasClass('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
        });

        // Clean up any placeholders if the page is refreshed
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            $('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder') && $(this).hasClass('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
        };
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact none of the IE's as of Oct 19th 2011 support the placeholder attribute.  I've tested it in 7, 8, and 9 and none of them seem to recognize it.  You'd think ie9, seeing as how it's supposed to support css3 and html5 would have fixed this but it does not appear so.

As a simple workaround that isn't pretty but gets the job done you can use some javascript like this:

```
<input type="text" value="Enter ZIP"
  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter ZIP'){this.value = '';}" />
```

Comment: That won't return the value `onblur`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in one of my projects. The only thing is that I only needed a placeholder on one element, so it might not work for your situation right away. But just to get the idea of how simple the code is:

```
(function(){
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('your-id-here');
    var placeHolderSupport = ("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"));
    if( !placeHolderSupport )
    {
        //show hint in gray
        var placeholder = nameInput.getAttribute('placeholder');
        nameInput.onfocus = function(){ if(this.value==placeholder){this.value='';this.className='';} };
        nameInput.onblur  = function(){ if(this.value==''){this.value=placeholder;this.className='placeholder';} };
        nameInput.onblur();
    }
})()
```