# Add input attribute with jQuery prop no work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

Because I can't add a `placeholder` attribut at `input` tag in my server code, so I need to use the jQuery to dynamically add this attribut when DOM is ready. So I write the following code, I tested it that works well in Chrome, Firefox and IE7, IE8, but it does't work well in IE9.

```
$(function () {
    $('input').prop('placeholder', 'value');
}
```

Are there other jQuery methods can do this?

#### Update:

Yes, I know `placeholder` is not support by IE9, and the [`jquery-placeholder`](http://mths.be/placeholder) plugin was used in my pages, but this plugin need to check the `placeholder` attr of `input` tags, so I need to use `jQuery` to add this attr, let this plugin to work.

Comment: What it gives?? any error? Checked console?

Comment: try $('input').attr('placeholder','value')

Comment: Why adding them dynamically? Moreover, also if you can add them, IE < 10 doesn't support placeholder at all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765794/placeholder-attribute-not-supported-in-ie-any-suggestions Chk this

Comment: @DhavalMarthak There is no error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try using .attr() function for jQuery, but Placeholders are not supported on IE.

```
$(function () {
    $("input").attr("placeholder","Value");
}
```

But you can use this [placeholder polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) .

Comment: Thank you, `$("input").attr("placeholder","Value");` is working.

Comment: "not supported on IE" < 10

Comment: @roasted that's why i placed the placeholder polyfill

Comment: I was just responding to your statement: "Placeholders are not supported on IE"   Placeholders are now supported under IE10.  +1 nice post :)

Comment: @roasted yes, your right but my problem is that Windows 8 sucks :P and i don't have the IE10 yet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since `placeholder` attr is not supported by all browser, you need a jQuery solution. You can use this plugin:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think question is duplicate and the answer is already mentioned here

[Placeholder attribute not supported in IE. Any suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765794/placeholder-attribute-not-supported-in-ie-any-suggestions)